# Group all the fields in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a request to group all the fields in one row?

**Table:**

```
id | type
---------
1  | 1
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
3  | 3
```

**query:**

```
select concat('id(', count(type), ')') from T group by id;
```

**output:**

```
id(2)
id(1)
id(2)
```

I want to get a string like: `'id(1)' = 2, 'id(2)' = 1, 'id(3)' = 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do it in two stages.  Make your `id(n) = x` records, then GROUP_CONCAT() them.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(id_count SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM
  (SELECT CONCAT('id(', id, ') = ', count(type)) id_count FROM T GROUP BY id) data
```

But do note that this is often a sign of a SQL Anti-Pattern.

It is normally recommended to not compress multiple values into a single value.  And it is normally recommended to keep presentation and data layer separate.